# 500 Server Error when trying to add a new mimetype

Tags: xml, web-config, mime-types

I'm trying to add the mimeType application/xml to web.config, but everytime I add it I get a 500 server error. I have no experience with this and any help would be very appreciated.

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/> 
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="application/xml " />
</system.webServer>
```